# Hosting Roboto Font in nextjs

Tags: css, next.js, roboto

I'm trying to host Google Roboto Font in my website. I have inspected the font-family, and the network. I think the font file is hosted and imported successfully. But I'm confused that the "Rendered Fonts" shown below is "PingFang SC". Where it came from?? T.T

[image: chrome inspect css]

[image: chrome inspect network]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It's because roboto is only for latin and number, I used Chinese characters here...